# Как последовательно применить два having к запросу(чтобы во второй раз был набор с уже отсеянными первым)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Например:

```
...
GROUP BY post_id 
HAVING 
    _to = MAX(_to) 
HAVING 
    id = MAX(id)
```

То есть сначала отсеются те, у которых `_to` не максимален, а затем отсеются все, кроме одного(все равно какого, главное, чтобы один из группы остался)

Comment: Можно сделать вложенный select

Comment: @JVic как вариант. А штатными средствами такое не сделать?

Comment: Это и есть штатные средства, мне кажется что ваша задумка не сработает с хэвингом, я могу и ошибаться, я бы ещё поигрался с сортировкой и лимитом по первому элементу, но опять же без вложенного селекта не обойтись

Comment: @Jvic да, действительно, `having` так не работает. Поищу другие пути

Comment: Если интересно, сделал через `id = (select id ... _to = (MAX(_to)(с теми же where перед _to =)) AND out.post_id = post_id LIMIT 1)`

Comment: ??? достаточно обычного AND: `HAVING _to = MAX(_to) AND id = MAX(id)`. Формально... если бы что-то позволяло сравнивать значения поля в агрегатке со значением без агрегатки.  Ну а  "второй HAVING" вообще разумнее заменить на сортировку плюс LIMIT.